# Clean html with HtmlCleaner

Tags: java, android, htmlcleaner

I have a html file stored on the phone and I want to clean it with HtmlCleaner and see the output result. Here's my code:

```
public void cleanHtml() throws IOException{
    HtmlCleaner cleaner = new HtmlCleaner();

    CleanerProperties props = cleaner.getProperties();

    TagNode node = cleaner.clean(htmlToClean);

    new PrettyXmlSerializer(props).writeToFile(node, "4c.xml");
}
```

This doesn't do anything. I want to see the .xml or cleaned .html file somewhere on my phone.

This is htmlToClean variable:

```
htmlToClean = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Android/data/com.whizzapps.stpsurniki/4c.html");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it like this:

```
private class cleanHtml extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        try {
            HtmlCleaner cleaner = new HtmlCleaner();
            String url = "https://www.easistent.com/urniki/263/razredi/16515";
            TagNode node = cleaner.clean(new URL(url));
            CleanerProperties props = cleaner.getProperties();
            String fileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Android/data/com.whizzapps.stpsurniki/cleaned.html";
            new PrettyXmlSerializer(props).writeToFile(node, fileName, "utf-8");
            Log.i("TAG", "AsyncTask done!");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```